# Dev-C++ rearanging and deleting my code

Tags: c++, ide, dev-c++

As I write code in Dev-C++ and scroll around to write another function and come back to the previous function I was working on Dev-C++ will have had entirely deleted my previous function! It also puts my code in all different places all over the screen randomly, messes up my code when I do edit --> undo and will give me error statements when I don't even have errors. I am running Windows 8. Can anybody help me get this straightened up please? It recently messed up a very large product I was working on with over 500 lines of code so I am rather upset about it. Thank you very much in advance for any help or any suggestions of other simple IDEs.

Comment: Isn't Dev-C++ supposed to be like the worst IDE in the world?  Use VisualStudio or vim.

Comment: ...or NetBeans, Eclipse CDT, QtCreator... Didn't know, that Dev-C++ is still around. I was under the impression it has been abandoned a long while ago.

Comment: What version of Dev-C++?  You should be using [Orwell Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) as the currently maintained fork of the original Bloodshed Dev-C++.  You may do better with Code::Blocks or Visual Studio Express however unless Orwell has fixed the abysmal Dev-C++ debugger interface.

Comment: I will definitely give Orwell Dev-C++ a go. Thank you very much! :)